# Wrong input shape for multistep timeseries prediction (keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, keras

I have Open,High,Low and Close (OHLC) prices for a stock, and I want to predict the next 6 OHLC values.

The data looks like this:

```
[[ 2166.99  2149.97  2168.88  2165.63]
 [ 2165.86  2158.48  2166.88  2164.88]
 [ 2166.69  2162.17  2167.13  2166.13]
 ..., 
 [ 2181.32  2178.06  2184.38  2178.5 ]
 [ 2183.87  2179.69  2184.75  2183.32]
 [ 2183.51  2181.78  2184.07  2183.07]]
```

I also have a 3D Array that holds the values that should be predicted which looks like this:

```
[[[ 2165.86  2158.48  2166.88  2164.88]
  [ 2166.69  2162.17  2167.13  2166.13]
  [ 2167.26  2164.43  2167.88  2166.8 ]
  [ 2167.37  2165.84  2167.62  2166.87]
  [ 2167.73  2166.61  2168.12  2167.37]
  [ 2168.92  2167.17  2170.12  2167.62]]

 [[ 2166.69  2162.17  2167.13  2166.13]
  [ 2167.26  2164.43  2167.88  2166.8 ]
  [ 2167.37  2165.84  2167.62  2166.87]
  [ 2167.73  2166.61  2168.12  2167.37]
  [ 2168.92  2167.17  2170.12  2167.62]
  [ 2170.23  2168.04  2171.13  2169.8 ]]
 ...,
```

I know this data is not normalized, but I think it won't matter on this topic.

The code (which I found somewhere) looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4), input_shape=(1, 4)))

# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 8)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# subsequent layers: no need for input_shape
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation='softmax')))

# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 32)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
print("Model compiled.")
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected timedistributed_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1793, 4)
```

I know I have to reshape the Xtrain array, but I don't know what to reshape it to look like, especially with this target array. Also, what layers would be the best for this application?

Comment: I am having virtually the same problem! Did you find a solution and could you post it here? Tnx

Comment: I ended up solving the problem but I don't have the sourcecode anymore, sorry.